# OAuth 2.0 required, legacy auth no longer supported, on 10-1 or 9-1?

Tags: facebook, legacy, authentication, oauth-2.0

In the FB Developer roadmap, it seems to indicate that the deadline for upgrading apps/websites to use OAuth 2.0 is 10-1-11 (http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/) .  But in a blog post, it listed the deadline as 9-1-11 (http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/497).

Does anyone know which date is correct?

Answer (score 1):

A [more recent blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/534/) says October 1st, which is consistent with the roadmap which does get updated often.